# Go to definition missing in Spyder 4.0..0

Tags: python, spyder, kite

Go to definition is completely missing from my Spyder 4.0.0 installation (Python3.7 parallel install) on Arch Linux. I've gone into the settings and enabled 'Go to definition' in the introspection tab, but that didn't help. I have the latest version of Kite installed as well. Strangely, I believe 'Go to definition' is present *and* working on an identical environment setup on my other computer. How can I re-enable 'Go to definition', it's completely disrupting my coding.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me with winpython 3.8.1

```
pip uninstall pexpect
```

then:

```
pip install pexpect
```

Note that --upgrade will not work.

Finally I ran "Spyder reset.exe"